# How to make SDN6 to set node field value from numeric sequence when not set manually?

Tags: kotlin, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am using Spring Data Neo4j v6 (latest) and need to create nodes with numeric field (customerNumber in example node below). Field should be:

- either set by client on node creation time (value inside specific range, for example 1-1000)
- or if not set by client, should get value automatically from numeric sequence (for example starting from 1001)

```
@Node
data class Customer(
    @Id val id: String,
    val name: String,
    val customerNumber: Long?
)
```

There is separate @Id field in node, so customerNumber can not be id (if that matters). But customerNumber must still be unique.

Does SDN6 offer some way to implement this?

Comment: Creating a Sequence-node as suggested [here](https://community.neo4j.com/t/integer-sequence-generator-in-neo4j-apoc/5713) probably solves my problem. I am still hoping to find "SDN6 way" to implement this, maybe something similar to @GeneratedValue and IdGenerator-interface with ids. Let me know if such way exists.